# How to draw fibonacci sequence using turtle module

Tags: python, fibonacci, turtle-graphics

This is my first question ever, and I am a complete and utter beginner, so please don't eat me :) What I am trying to to is to draw a fibonacci sequence using the Python turtle module. My code is as follows:

```
import turtle

zuf = turtle.Turtle()

while True:

  zuf.forward(10)
  zuf.left(3.1415)
```

This, however, drives around in circles only. I have tried to create a variable, say X, and assign a fibonacci rule to it `xn = xn-1 + xn-2` then I'd put it in here `zuf.forward(x)` but it doesn't work.  I tried multiple variations of that, but none seems to work. Please don't give a whole solution, only some hint, thanks a lot.

Comment: You asked for a hint, I found this: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Fibonacci-Sequence-on-Turtle maybe you'd like to give it a quick look just to get a basic idea, seems they use `for` loops instead :) good luck

Comment: Thank you buddy : )

Comment: import turtle

zuf = turtle.Turtle()
n = 0
y = (n-1)+(n-2)


while True:

  zuf.forward(y)
  zuf.left(3.1415)         this doesn't seem to work neither

Answer (score 3):

I think I can get you from where you are to where you want to be.  First, your invocation of:

```
zuf.left(3.1415)
```

seems to indicate you're thinking in *radians*, which is fine.  But you need to tell your turtle that:

```
zuf = turtle.Turtle()
zuf.radians()
```

this will still make your code go in circles, but very different circles.  Next, we want to replace `10` with our fibonacci value.  Before the `while` loop, initialize your fibonacci counters:

```
previous, current = 0, 1
```

as the last statement in the `while` loop, bump them up:

```
previous, current = current, current + previous
```

and in your `forward()` call, replace `10` with `current`.  Next, we need to turn the line that it's drawing into a square.  To do this, we need to do two things. First, loop the drawing code four times:

```
for i in range(4):
    zuf.forward(current)
    zuf.left(3.1415)
```

And second, replace your angle with pi/2 instead:

```
    zuf.left(3.1415 / 2)
```

If you assemble this all correctly, you should end up with a figure like:

[image]

showing the increasing size of the fibonacci values.  Not the greatest looking image, you'll still have to do some work on it to clean it up to look nice.

Finally, I was impressed with the fibonacci drawing code that @IvanS95 linked to in his comment, that I wrote a high speed version of it that uses *stamping* instead of *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SCALE = 5
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

square = Turtle('square', visible=False)
square.fillcolor('white')
square.speed('fastest')
square.right(90)
square.penup()

previous_scaled, previous, current = 0, 0, 1

for _ in range(10):
    current_scaled = current * SCALE
    square.forward(current_scaled/2 + previous_scaled/2)
    square.shapesize(current_scaled / CURSOR_SIZE)
    square.left(90)
    square.forward(current_scaled/2 - previous_scaled/2)
    square.stamp()
    previous_scaled, previous, current = current_scaled, current, current + previous

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

This is not a whole solution for you, only a hint of what can be done as you're drawing your squares and this is a stamp-based solution which plays by different rules.